# What are the possible return values for send, sendto and sendmsg on a UDP socket on Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, posix, datagram

These functions return -1 on error and the input length on success. Under what conditions may they return a value less than the length and greater than or equal to 0 for an UDP socket on Linux?

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320622/udp-non-blocking-socket-on-a-real-time-os-sendto-and-recvfrom-can-return-wi) is similar but in the context of a non-Linux RTOS. The answers assert it cannot happen, and the OS vendor contradicts them. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931570/dealing-with-sendto-failure-for-udp-socket) is similar but the accepted answer only discusses receipt. [Beej's guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#sendtorecv) asserts that it may happen. [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/6b5aa669db4d57231e21b1ee97c63a06167e117e/src/unix/udp.c#L458) asserts that it cannot. POSIX does not seem to forbid it.

Therefore, I am curious what circumstances, if any, lead to a "short write" return value for UDP sockets on Linux? Is there an internet RFC or clause in POSIX which forbids it? Can this occur, for example, if a UDP datagram is fragmented (sent in multiple IP packets)?

Answer (score 2):

UDP is a datagram protocol, i.e. it is not a byte stream as TCP but there are clear message boundaries inside the protocol. These message semantics are reflected when reading, i.e. a single `recv` will return a single (and full) message.

A single message (datagram) is send with a single `send` and there is no other way to specify the message boundary. But a "short send" would introduce message boundaries where they don't belong and thus should not be possible for UDP.